# What is the correct way to clean and lubricate the chain of a Yamaha FZ 16?

Tags: motorcycle, cleaning, lubrication, chain

I own a 2011 Yamaha FZ 16 bike; which has an open chain; occasionally dirt gets accumulated to the chain and despite my many attempts I am unable to properly clean the chain.

Also could you also help me on how to lubricate the chain of the bike.

Comment: As for the chain lubrication, buy a (spray) can of good chain lube and apply a layer to the inside of the chain (i.e., the side of the chain that has direct contact with the two sprockets.) This is easily done with a helper pushing the bike forward and you lubricating (or, if you have a stand, use that). ([random video illustrating chain lubrication](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wNSGEzbDxKY))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- put the bike up on a rear stand
- clean the chain - use a degreaser designed for the purpose and a stiff nylon brush, wash a few bits at a time spinning the wheel to access more portions of the chain
- rinse off the degreaser
- use a water repellent to get rid of the water
- dry off with a rag
- use a good quality chain lube in a spray (there are different types based on the conditions you ride in i.e. wet, hot, cold, sandy/dusty)
- wipe off excess with a clean rag

I found my chain to be substanstially cleaner and require less maintenance once I fitted a scottoiler (other chain oilers are available) than when I didnt.